# Dropping temporary columns in Spark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

Im creating a new column in a data frame and use it in subsequent transformations. Latter when I try to drop the new column it breaks the execution. When I look into the execution plan Spark optimize execution plan by removing the whole flow as because Im dropping the column in latter stage. How to drop temporary column without affecting execution plan? - Im using pyspark.

```
df = df.withColumn('COLUMN_1', "some transformation returns value").withColumn('COLUMN_2',"some transformation returns value")
df = df.withColumn('RESULT',when("some condition", col('COLUMN_1')).otherwise(col('COLUMN_2'))).drop('COLUMN_1','COLUMN_2')
```

Comment: Hi @syv, why selecting the involved only columns and excluding the one that you need to drop does not work?

Comment: share with us a *minimal* code snippet of what you do, and what you mean by temporary column

Comment: When we select the same principle applied - Spark removes whole execution plan for the attributes which are excluded.

Comment: Included sample code which Im trying to achieve

Comment: I could solve this by caching first statement ... but I couldnt understand what is going on underneeth when I cache it and how it works? - Any help?

Comment: I can't reproduce this. Please provide an mcve and tell us the spark version.

Comment: @syv try to not mutate the same variable -> try daisy chaining the dataframes instead, such as `df1 = df.withColumn(...); df2 = df1.withColumn(...)`. I think I have seen this bug before.

Answer (score 0):

[I have tried in spark-shell(using scala) and it's working as expected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2QWDo.png)

I'm using Spark 2.4.4 version and scala 2.11.12.

I have tried the same in Pyspark and refer the attachment. Let me know if this answer helps for you.

[With Pyspark](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0uMgk.png)